# How to determine if an element is above viewport?

Tags: javascript

How do I determine in javascript, if an element is above the viewport (user has scrolled past it) (not just if it can be seen)?

In this snippet:
console.log(iselement1aboveviewport); would return:

- 0, if you have not seen the element (element is below viewport)
- 0, if you currently see the element (element is in the viewport)
- 1, if you have scrolled past the element (element is above the viewport).

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam et imperdiet nulla. Morbi malesuada consectetur nisl, ut iaculis sapien. Praesent molestie lobortis purus efficitur vehicula. Quisque elementum tortor sit amet condimentum rhoncus. Etiam molestie porttitor nisi, vel porttitor orci dignissim a. Aliquam a est felis. Quisque libero neque, ultricies a nunc nec, hendrerit euismod ligula. Vestibulum viverra egestas magna malesuada ornare. Sed in cursus est, eget convallis arcu.

Integer ante lorem, sagittis quis turpis quis, congue feugiat risus. Cras mollis porttitor rutrum. Fusce eget nisi ut nisl bibendum sollicitudin. Donec tempus accumsan elit, ut hendrerit odio commodo ut. Sed ac interdum massa. Vivamus elementum efficitur nulla sit amet varius. Suspendisse purus mi, laoreet eget ligula molestie, egestas sodales erat.

<div id="element1" style="color: orange;">Am I above the viewport? (have you scrolled past me?)</div>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam et imperdiet nulla. Morbi malesuada consectetur nisl, ut iaculis sapien. Praesent molestie lobortis purus efficitur vehicula. Quisque elementum tortor sit amet condimentum rhoncus. Etiam molestie porttitor nisi, vel porttitor orci dignissim a. Aliquam a est felis. Quisque libero neque, ultricies a nunc nec, hendrerit euismod ligula. Vestibulum viverra egestas magna malesuada ornare. Sed in cursus est, eget convallis arcu.

Fusce gravida tellus fermentum massa faucibus scelerisque. Vestibulum consequat dolor libero, sed lobortis ligula eleifend at. Sed porttitor odio nec enim pulvinar pulvinar. Vivamus vulputate sollicitudin nisi et ullamcorper. Aenean et ultrices nunc. Donec ligula dolor, lobortis in vestibulum at, ultrices ac lectus. Nunc tristique arcu eu felis finibus commodo. Ut lacinia tincidunt dui, venenatis lacinia orci imperdiet in.

Nam maximus at quam eu rhoncus. Mauris auctor efficitur dignissim. Proin porttitor nunc ut tortor aliquet, a tincidunt tortor luctus. Suspendisse dapibus dui sapien, sed elementum ex pellentesque a. Quisque tortor massa, pretium vel lacus non, accumsan convallis leo. Nunc nec orci mi. Phasellus id massa ipsum. Aenean non ornare neque, ultricies vestibulum tellus. Aliquam quis laoreet orci. Cras faucibus massa in ultricies consectetur. Duis et odio nec dolor sollicitudin condimentum.

Integer ante lorem, sagittis quis turpis quis, congue feugiat risus. Cras mollis porttitor rutrum. Fusce eget nisi ut nisl bibendum sollicitudin. Donec tempus accumsan elit, ut hendrerit odio commodo ut. Sed ac interdum massa. Vivamus elementum efficitur nulla sit amet varius. Suspendisse purus mi, laoreet eget ligula molestie, egestas sodales erat.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)

Comment: Not, I need to also know, if an element is also above the viewport.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Explanation:

You should use [`Element.getBoundingClientRect`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect)

> The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns the size of an element and its position relative to the viewport.

It returns an object that looks like this:

```
{
  "x": 7.997159004211426,
  "y": 229.81533813476562,
  "width": 425.8238525390625,
  "height": 18.18181800842285,
  "top": 229.81533813476562,
  "right": 433.8210115432739,
  "bottom": 247.99715614318848,
  "left": 7.997159004211426
}
```

If you want to know when the element is above the view port you need to keep an eye on the `bottom` property to be <= 0.

### Working example:

```js
const element1 = document.getElementById("element1");


window.addEventListener("scroll", function(){
  console.clear();
  console.log(element1.getBoundingClientRect().bottom <= 0 ? "Above" : "Under");
});
```

```html
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam et imperdiet nulla. Morbi malesuada consectetur nisl, ut iaculis sapien. Praesent molestie lobortis purus efficitur vehicula. Quisque elementum tortor sit amet condimentum rhoncus. Etiam molestie porttitor nisi, vel porttitor orci dignissim a. Aliquam a est felis. Quisque libero neque, ultricies a nunc nec, hendrerit euismod ligula. Vestibulum viverra egestas magna malesuada ornare. Sed in cursus est, eget convallis arcu.

Integer ante lorem, sagittis quis turpis quis, congue feugiat risus. Cras mollis porttitor rutrum. Fusce eget nisi ut nisl bibendum sollicitudin. Donec tempus accumsan elit, ut hendrerit odio commodo ut. Sed ac interdum massa. Vivamus elementum efficitur nulla sit amet varius. Suspendisse purus mi, laoreet eget ligula molestie, egestas sodales erat.

<div id="element1" style="color: orange;">Am I above the viewport? (have you scrolled past me?)</div>

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam et imperdiet nulla. Morbi malesuada consectetur nisl, ut iaculis sapien. Praesent molestie lobortis purus efficitur vehicula. Quisque elementum tortor sit amet condimentum rhoncus. Etiam molestie porttitor nisi, vel porttitor orci dignissim a. Aliquam a est felis. Quisque libero neque, ultricies a nunc nec, hendrerit euismod ligula. Vestibulum viverra egestas magna malesuada ornare. Sed in cursus est, eget convallis arcu.

Fusce gravida tellus fermentum massa faucibus scelerisque. Vestibulum consequat dolor libero, sed lobortis ligula eleifend at. Sed porttitor odio nec enim pulvinar pulvinar. Vivamus vulputate sollicitudin nisi et ullamcorper. Aenean et ultrices nunc. Donec ligula dolor, lobortis in vestibulum at, ultrices ac lectus. Nunc tristique arcu eu felis finibus commodo. Ut lacinia tincidunt dui, venenatis lacinia orci imperdiet in.

Nam maximus at quam eu rhoncus. Mauris auctor efficitur dignissim. Proin porttitor nunc ut tortor aliquet, a tincidunt tortor luctus. Suspendisse dapibus dui sapien, sed elementum ex pellentesque a. Quisque tortor massa, pretium vel lacus non, accumsan convallis leo. Nunc nec orci mi. Phasellus id massa ipsum. Aenean non ornare neque, ultricies vestibulum tellus. Aliquam quis laoreet orci. Cras faucibus massa in ultricies consectetur. Duis et odio nec dolor sollicitudin condimentum.

Integer ante lorem, sagittis quis turpis quis, congue feugiat risus. Cras mollis porttitor rutrum. Fusce eget nisi ut nisl bibendum sollicitudin. Donec tempus accumsan elit, ut hendrerit odio commodo ut. Sed ac interdum massa. Vivamus elementum efficitur nulla sit amet varius. Suspendisse purus mi, laoreet eget ligula molestie, egestas sodales erat.
```